# How to use a javascript onclick event to store information to the database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

A customer is logged into the system, they want to book a class through the calendar. Once they click a class to book they are presented with an alert box asking if they would like to book a class. Once they click ok I want this users unique id, and the class to store to the 'class' database table. The code in my classes.php file is:

```
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //set edit to true
    //editable:true,
    header:{
        //what to view
     left:'prev,next',
     center:'title',
     right:''
    },
    events: 'load.php',


    eventClick:function(event)
    {
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to book this class?"))
     {
      var id = event.id;
      $.ajax({
       url:"book.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, thisUser:thisUser},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Event Booked");
       }
      })
     }
    },

   });
  });

  </script>
```

The code to book the class in the 'book.php' file is:

```
 if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO class 
 (title, start_event, end_event, cust_id) 
 VALUES (:title, :start_event, :end_event, :thisUser)
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':title'  => $_POST['title'],
   ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
   ':end_event' => $_POST['end'],
   ':cust_id' => $_POST['thisUser']
  )
 );
}
```

I can't get anything to store in my database.

Comment: Check your console for any network errors

Comment: Okay, and what _is_ happening? What debugging have you done?  You have an ajax request.  Is that request being made?  If so, what is the response?  If not, what have you done to narrow down _why_ it's not?  Where are the variables used in your `data` object in the ajax function defined?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz it is coming up title is not defined. I have only ever done this with a form not an alert so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: my database goes like: id, title, start_event, end_event, cust_id

Comment: @JessicaByers `title:title` Where is var `title` at? it is not defined

Comment: try to echo or console.log all the values you need, and see if you are getting an actual value back